# Laravel 5 says: "Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'", but I have 'author_id'

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5

I have user and post models have this relation:

```
// BlogPost
public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

// User
public function articles() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\BlogPost');
}
```

In database I have "blog_posts" table with "author_id" field, but Laravel returns this error:
 "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'".
What can I do?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the error pass the foreign key name as second argument for the `articles` relation defined in `User` model

```
// User model 
public function articles() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\BlogPost', 'author_id');
}
```

**Explanation**

In a `hasMany` or `hasOne` relation Laravel will use the class name to derive the foreign key if no foreign key name is passed as the second argument.

It will derive the name as follows.

1. Get the class name
2. Convert it into snake case
3. Append `_id`

So in your case the `articles` relation defined under `User` will use a foreign key named `user_id` as you haven't provided a foreign key name which is not the correct foreign key.

---

In a `belongsTo` relation Laravel will use the relation name to derive the foreign key if no foreign key name is passed as the second parameter.

It will derive the name as follows.

1. Get the relation name (function name or the 4th argument)
2. Convert it into snake case
3. Append `_id`

So in your case the `author` relation defined under `BlogPost` will correctly derive the foreign key named `author_id`

Comment: Excellent answer! Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

when you don't match with Laravel naming standard you must pass your foreign key:

```
public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have author_id as the column name in which you are saving the user id then rewrite the functions as below:

```
// BlogPost
public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','author_id');
}
```

Comment: I think, we don't need to mention the second argument as the field is "author_id" and the function name is "author". But both didn't work as I said in next answer. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No it is not depend on the function name actually. It is looking for the `modelname_id` always. E.g. you have `Post` and `Comment` are two models then you should have `post_id` as the `foreign key column name` in `comments` table to save the `post auto incremented id`. But if you have any other name regardless of `modelname_id` then you have to provide it as second argument to this function to match the record with that value of column.

Comment: ok, I used second argument "author_id" in belongsTo and it didn't work, then I placed "author_id" as the second argument of hasMany and it worked!

Comment: what table structure do you have for BlogPost

Answer (score 0):

Alireva ....That is how is supposed to be since the column author_id is in BlogPost table which is relating to a user table.

You are telling a user to look for the relation in BlogPost using a column in that table called author_id and not what you would expect that is user_id

Answer (score 0):

In blog_posts you should set user_id instead of author_id.
As default, Laravel set tablename_id in relationship, in your case : user_id.